# Calculate the SUM of the Column which has Time DataType:

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, time, sum

I want to calculate the Sum of the Field which has Time DataType.

My Table is Below:

```
  TableA:

            TotalTime
          -------------
             12:18:00
             12:18:00
```

Here I want to sum the two time fields.
I tried the below Query

```
   SELECT CAST(
              DATEADD(MS, SUM(DATEDIFF(MS, '00:00:00.000', 
                CONVERT(TIME, TotalTime))), '00:00:00.000'
               ) AS TOTALTIME) 
    FROM [TableA]
```

But it gives the Output as

```
            TOTALTIME
        -----------------
         00:36:00.0000000
```

But My Desired Output would be like below:

```
            TOTALTIME
        -----------------
            24:36:00
```

How to get this Output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could sum the total number of seconds, or `datediff(second,0,datecolumn)`.  You can format that as a time string with some math.  For example, the total number of minutes is `totalseconds / 60 % 60`.  For example:

```
select  cast(sum(datediff(second,0,dt))/3600 as varchar(12)) + ':' + 
        right('0' + cast(sum(datediff(second,0,dt))/60%60 as varchar(2)),2) +
        ':' + right('0' + cast(sum(datediff(second,0,dt))%60 as varchar(2)),2)
from    TestTable
```

[Working code at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/23503/2)

Comment: Its Working, But the problem is 
When adding the times ('12:04:00'),('12:05:00') it gives the correct o/p as "24:09:00". But when we add ('12:05:00'),('12:05:00'), it gives the o/p as "24:01:00".. This is because in the Minutes part if we give varchar(3), then it shows as "24:010:00".

Comment: You're right, the `cast('0' + ...` I used to prefix a `0` didn't work.  Fixed the answer with `right('0' + ...` now.

Answer (score 0):

24:36 is the same as 00:36(Next day)

Comment: Yes. I can understand. But I need to Display it as "24:36". How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your query is working fine the results are correct,

24:36 is the time  00:36 for next day.

You can display maximum 24 hrs. You are not using any day thats why every 24 hrs =0 hrs for next day.

Just change the column values and you can see that.

Comment: Yes. I can understand. But I need to Display it as "24:36". How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It would be a tad longwinded, but if you wanted to avoid the day rollover but you could split the second TIME into constituent datepart()'s and then add those on? (even display as a varchar if it's necessary to have an hour value greater than 24.

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS.

```
SELECT 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),SUM(DATEPART(HH,CAST(YOUR_FIELD AS DATETIME)))+ 
(SUM(DATEPART(MINUTE,CAST(YOUR_FIELD AS DATETIME)))/60) + 
(SUM(DATEPART(MINUTE,CAST(YOUR_FIELD AS DATETIME)))%60 + 
(SUM(DATEPART(SECOND,CAST(YOUR_FIELD AS DATETIME)))/60))/60) + ':' +
RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), 
(SUM(DATEPART(MINUTE,CAST(YOUR_FIELD AS DATETIME)))%60+ 
(SUM(DATEPART(SECOND,CAST(YOUR_FIELD AS DATETIME)))/60))%60),2) + ':' +   
RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),SUM(DATEPART(SECOND, 
    CAST(YOUR_FIELD AS DATETIME)))%60),2) AS YOUR_FIELD

FROM YOUR_TABLE
```