# How to add time (like 9:25:03 + 11:36:27 = ) of single column in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

i have column(time datatype) which contains values like

```
9:25:03 
4:43:21 
2:50:13 
11:25:33
```

,what query should i write to get sum of all values in the column

Comment: How exactly do you define the sum of two times?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10830909/calculate-the-sum-of-the-column-which-has-time-datatype

Comment: actually m using this query - select * from ( select e.myhours,e.AccountProjectId, dbo.GetWeekDayNameOfDate(e.totaltime) as weekd, e.AccountEmployeeId from AccountEmployeeTimeEntry e) P pivot (
sum("myhours ") for weekd in([Monday], [Tuesday], [Wednesday], [thursday], [Friday], [Saturday], [Sunday] )
) as pvt   now here i want to sum all values present in the myhours column and ( data present in the column is  in this format 12:2:45 , 4:6:12 etc  )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn your times into seconds and sum them instead.

```
with YourTable(TimeCol) as
(
  select '9:25:03' union all
  select '4:43:21' union all
  select '2:50:13' union all
  select '11:25:33'
)

select sum(datediff(second, 0, TimeCol)) sumSeconds
from YourTable
```

Result:

```
sumSeconds
-----------
102250
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
;with cte as(
select SUM(DATEPART(hh,tm))*3600+
       SUM(DATEPART(MI,tm))*60+
       SUM(DATEPART(SS,tm)) tme
from time_table)
SELECT cast(datepart(hh,cast(CONVERT(varchar(8),
       DATEADD(ss, tme  , 0), 114) as time))+
       datediff(dd,'1900-01-01',CONVERT(varchar, 
       DATEADD(ss, tme  , 0), 121))*24 as varchar(20))+
       right(CONVERT(varchar(8), DATEADD(ss, tme  , 0), 114),6)
from cte
```

result

```
28:24:10
```

## [SQL Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b7450/3)

Comment: actually m using this query - select * from ( select e.myhours,e.AccountProjectId, dbo.GetWeekDayNameOfDate(e.totaltime) as weekd, e.AccountEmployeeId from AccountEmployeeTimeEntry e) P pivot (
sum("myhours ") for weekd in([Monday], [Tuesday], [Wednesday], [thursday], [Friday], [Saturday], [Sunday] )
) as pvt   now here i want to sum all values present in the myhours column and ( data present in the column is  in this format 12:2:45 , 4:6:12 etc  )

Comment: @MichaelCode: could u plz give the table structure for AccountEmployeeTimeEntry table

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
create table tbl123(tm time)

insert into tbl123
values('9:25:03'),('4:43:21'),('2:50:13'),('11:25:33')



;WITH CTE as(select SUM(DATEPART(hh,tm)) as hh,SUM(DATEPART(mi,tm)) as mm,SUM(DATEPART(ss,tm)) as ss from tbl123)

SELECT cast(hh+(mm+(ss/60))/60 as varchar(10))+':'+
       cast((((mm+(ss/60))%60)) as varchar(10))+':'+
       cast(ss%60 as varchar(10)) 
       from CTE
```

Result:

```
   28:24:10
```

Comment: actually m using this query - select * from ( select e.myhours,e.AccountProjectId, dbo.GetWeekDayNameOfDate(e.totaltime) as weekd, e.AccountEmployeeId from AccountEmployeeTimeEntry e) P pivot ( sum("myhours ") for weekd in([Monday], [Tuesday], [Wednesday], [thursday], [Friday], [Saturday], [Sunday] ) ) as pvt now here i want to sum all values present in the myhours column ( data present in the column is in this format 12:2:45 , 4:6:12 etc )