# SUM of time returns date part as well

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to do a `SUM` of time values, but the output is rendered as `1900-01-01 05:46:11.740`. Note the preceding date part `1900-01-01`. I only want the time value.

Below is an example of what I have tried:

`DATEADD(MS, SUM(DATEDIFF(MS, '00:00:00.000', R.[Result].value('(/Result/Time/text())[1]', 'datetime'))), '00:00:00.000')`

`R.[Result].value()` is an XML value with format `00:00:00.000`

Any idea what I am doing wrong please?

Comment: It would probably be better to do this in a language which has a data type for the notion of time *spans*. The only data type in T-SQL for `time` is for a time of day -adding two of those together doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This guy wanted to calculate the sum of the field which has the time datatype. 
The Answer on this post had a proper solution which may be helpful:

```
select  cast(sum(datediff(second,0,dt))/3600 as varchar(12)) + ':' + 
right('0' + cast(sum(datediff(second,0,dt))/60%60 as varchar(2)),2) +
':' + right('0' + cast(sum(datediff(second,0,dt))%60 as varchar(2)),2)
from    TestTable
```

Reference : [Calculate the SUM of the Column which has Time DataType:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10830909/calculate-the-sum-of-the-column-which-has-time-datatype)